# Deploy application with different name‏

Tags: cloudify

we are deploying an application with the rest api 2.7.0 and we realized that if we deploy the application with the same name of the service is't ok on the contrary if we change the name of aplication fails. for example applicationName: helloworld and applicationName: myhelloworld
any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Cloudify, application names must be unique. You can't have two applications with the same name. With regards to services, the fully qualified name of a service is:

[Application Name].[Service Name]

So a service name can be re-used in a different application.

You may want to copy the REST Error message you recieved to be sure that this is the problem.